# Flexitems not wrapping down and causing overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

im new to Flexbox and still trying to figure some things out. For some reason I can't figure out why the flex-items inside my *.tab* div elements aren't wrapping. I want the flexitems with the *.block* class to wrap down while keeping the *.tab* elements equal width.

can you guys help me out?

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background-color: #151d1c;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  max-width: 1320px;
  background: #272a21;
  padding: 30px 30px 27px 27px;
}

.calc {
  min-width: 0;
  gap: 6px;
  display: flex;
}

.tab {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1px;
}

.row {
  gap: 1px;
  display: flex;
  background: rgb(47, 50, 40);
  align-items: center;
}

.skill {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 148px;
  min-height: 28px;
}

.lvl {
  display: flex;
}

button {
  border: none;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
}
```

The example html is to large so I post it inside a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/udLwr8b4/3/

Comment: All relevant code must be **right in the question itself**, not on an external site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the flex container of .block divs are not set to wrap.

You have to set the `flex-wrap: wrap` to the wrapper of these .block divs.

```html
<div style="display: flex; gap: 6px; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: space-around;">
            <div class="block">....</div>
            <div class="block">....</div>
            <div class="block">....</div>
            <div class="block">....</div>
            <div class="block">....</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vxrswp9L/2/